# Minimal compile environment on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, c, windows, compiler-construction, nmake

Trying to compile this WinURL tool from source on Win 8.1:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/winurl/
(src zip on that page if you want to take a look)
The reason is that I want to change the keybinding from Win+W to something else as Win 8.1 takes over Win+W for search and the tool no longer works on Win 8.1

What are my choices for a minimal dev env on Win 8.1? I'm not interested in installing GBs of tools if I can get away with something very simple that just lets me compile the above. Would something like Cygwin gcc or MinGW work or do I need some sort of Visual Studio and if so is there a simple free edition I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a lightweight compiler-only solution, don't look beyond MinGW. You can install it and add its `bin` folder to the `Environment PATH` variable.
If you want an IDE too, I would recommend CodeBlocks, or DevC++.

I would recommend CodeBlocks over DevC++ as people report to DevC++ being slow, and also its development cycle is very slow.

These are all free and open source solutions. And lightweight.

Comment: The Makefile says to use nmake to build it. And then I see it has dependencies on cl, link, rc. Which of the tools above would work? Here's the Makefile:
`
#
# Use `nmake' to build.
#

CFLAGS = /nologo /W3 /YX /O2 /Yd /D_WINDOWS /DDEBUG /ML /Fd
LFLAGS = /incremental:no

.c.obj:
 cl $(COMPAT) $(CFLAGS) /c $*.c

LIBS = gdi32.lib user32.lib shell32.lib

all: winurl.exe

winurl.exe: winurl.obj winurl.res
 link $(LFLAGS) -out:winurl.exe winurl.obj winurl.res $(LIBS)

winurl.res: winurl.rc winurl.ico winurlsmall.ico
 rc -r winurl.rc

clean:
 del *.obj
`
...

Comment: Not sure how to correctly post a formatted Makefile, so here it is on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/KaxuFnTT

Answer (score 0):

I got it to compile just fine with MinGW using the following script:

```
del *.o winurl.exe
windres winurl.rc winurlres.o
gcc -c winurl.c
gcc -o winurl.exe winurl.o winurlres.o C:\MinGW\lib\libgdi32.a -mwindows
strip winurl.exe
del *.o
```